# How can a large matrix be compressed?

Tags: matrices, compression

I have a large matrix, around $10\times10$. Each individual element in the matrix itself is also a very large number, roughly of the order $10^{30}$.

I know that matrices can be used to solve linear equations. So if there is an equation $ax + by = c$ then can I denote the $10\times10$ matrix, $a$, using $x\text{ and }y$ which are just $2$ real numbers and $b\text{ and  }c$ which are matrices. Can this be used to compress the larger matrix?

If not, then is there any other way that I can use so that I can use some form of short expression which can be evaluated into the larger matrix?

Comment: For an arbitrary matrix, you can't compress it. Do you know any other information about the structure of the matrix? Could you perhaps post a sample matrix? (If you do, use Stack Exchange's code formatting: put 4 spaces at the start of each line of the matrix.)

Comment: There are many ways to generate large matrices from the small seed (like $n \times n$ identity matrix), but it is generally very hard to do it the opposite direction (i.e. from matrix generate a seed that could be later used to regenerate it) unless the matrix in question has very precisely defined structure (and even then it probably won't be easy). Good luck!

Comment: By the way, the theorem under section 9.2 of [the comp.compression FAQs](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/compression-faq/part1/section-8.html) justifies my first sentence. Don't be discouraged, though: if your matrix does have some further structure, you should be able to compress it.

Comment: apart from the dimensions of the matrix there is no other pattern in the structure. Perhaps I will find some luck converting the matrix into something else...

Comment: @ritratt: If there really is no pattern at all, then you won't be able to compress it. See that theorem I linked.

Comment: Assuming the numbers are integers, and you use efficient storage, you'll need roughly $1kb$ (one kilobyte) to store the matrix. Which isn't much these days. You could lose precision in the numbers if you want to compress it anyway.

Comment: Many application-based matrices have low-rank blocks on the off-diagonal. You may be able to replace these blocks by a low-rank approximation (based on an SVD). But $10 \times 10$ is too small to expect a reasonable compression for the extra hassle you get for introducing the decompositions.

Comment: As with @Laray 's comment, you might wish to look up singular value decomposition. It rearranges the middle 10x10 matrix into diagonal matrix with largest coefficient first, and then sorted in decreasing values. If the 10x10 matrix has say 3 large coefficients, and 7 other nearly 0 coefficients, then we can approximately use a 3x3 matrix to represent the originally larger 10x10 matrix while still processing the inputs and outputs mostly unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

A $10\times10$ matrix is considered tiny and one can wonder whether it is worth compressing it.

A typical way to represent sparse matrices (i.e. with many zeroes) is to list the nonzero coefficients together with their indices. Several variants of this scheme are possible.

The sparse representation is more suitable for iterative resolution methods that essentially involve matrix/vector products. It is less amenable to direct resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In general, nothing can be compressed losslessly unless you are removing some sort of redundancies. The redundancy can be in some form of "pattern" which is not always obvious. Or, it is possible that some values repeat more often than usual and so, you represent those values by something "smaller". For generic data compression, check out Huffman encoding or the Lempel Ziv algorithm.